# Read sequence of JSON objects with spaces and commas in between with Python

Tags: python, json

I have never had experience with parsing JSON files until last week when I was given this task: to read 23 MB JSON file with some Python script and store some specific data to CSV. I've been searching a lot last days how to parse it, seen different implementations how one can do it with Python, but nothing works in my case. There is an example of JSON objects in the file:

```
 {
        "created": "2017-01-19T04:39:41.012",
        "expired": "2017-01-21T04:39:41.012",
        "id": "0000e0be-d2c6-4a89-ad37-8f71d0dd9e9a",
        "mixed": false,
        "pool_id": "189591",
        "reward": 0.5,
        "status": "EXPIRED",
        "task_suite_id": "f1aa98d6-ff25-4dde-81f5-2587ccbe36af",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "id": "ffbc4048-cc5a-4578-b0d9-0705a588b55d",
                "input_values": {
                    "address-ru": "\u0420\u043e\u0441\u0441\u0438\u044f, \u0421\u0432\u0435\u0440\u0434\u043b\u043e\u0432\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f \u043e\u0431\u043b\u0430\u0441\u0442\u044c, \u041f\u0435\u0440\u0432\u043e\u0443\u0440\u0430\u043b\u044c\u0441\u043a, 1-\u044f \u041f\u0438\u043b\u044c\u043d\u0430\u044f \u0443\u043b\u0438\u0446\u0430",
                    "company-id": "1542916387",
                    "coordinates": "56.91969408920,60.03087172680",
                    "country": "RU",
                    "language": "RU",
                    "name-ru": "\u0421\u0443\u043f\u0435\u0440\u043c\u0430\u0440\u043a\u0435\u0442",
                    "org-weight": "30",
                    "rubric": [
                        {
                            "name-ru": "\u0421\u0443\u043f\u0435\u0440\u043c\u0430\u0440\u043a\u0435\u0442",
                            "rubric-id": 184108079
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "user_id": "165684b434e6390fb8da262978601397"
    },
    {
        "created": "2017-02-24T16:08:10.280",
        "expired": "2017-02-26T16:08:10.280",
        "id": "0001b81e-dbcc-4de3-985d-4397b97dbffa",
        "mixed": false,
        "pool_id": "189591",
        "reward": 0.5,
        "status": "EXPIRED",
        "task_suite_id": "5dcbbd70-e570-4026-8246-a30bb462f35d",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "id": "90437e00-d15c-4679-b7be-6d3660efdbce",
                "input_values": {
                    "address-ru": "\u041c\u043e\u0441\u043a\u043e\u0432\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f \u043e\u0431\u043b., \u041a\u043e\u0440\u043e\u043b\u0435\u0432, \u043c\u0438\u043a\u0440\u043e\u0440\u0430\u0439\u043e\u043d \u0412\u0430\u043b\u0435\u043d\u0442\u0438\u043d\u043e\u0432\u043a\u0430, \u0443\u043b. \u0413\u043e\u0440\u044c\u043a\u043e\u0433\u043e, 12, \u043a\u043e\u0440\u043f.\u0412",
                    "company-id": "662316782",
                    "coordinates": "55.915326,37.869891",
                    "country": "RU",
                    "language": "RU",
                    "meta": [
                        {
                            "permlink-id": 1119957838
                        }
                    ],
                    "name-ru": "\u041d\u0435\u0430\u0442\u044d\u043b",
                    "org-weight": "30",
                    "rubric": [
                        {
                            "name-ru": "\u0420\u0435\u043c\u043e\u043d\u0442 \u0438\u0437\u043c\u0435\u0440\u0438\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c\u043d\u044b\u0445 \u043f\u0440\u0438\u0431\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0432",
                            "rubric-id": 184106846
                        },
                        {
                            "name-ru": "\u0412\u043e\u0434\u043e\u0441\u0447\u0435\u0442\u0447\u0438\u043a\u0438, \u0433\u0430\u0437\u043e\u0441\u0447\u0435\u0442\u0447\u0438\u043a\u0438, \u0442\u0435\u043f\u043b\u043e\u0441\u0447\u0435\u0442\u0447\u0438\u043a\u0438",
                            "rubric-id": 184106834
                        },
                        {
                            "name-ru": "\u041e\u0442\u043e\u043f\u0438\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c\u043d\u043e\u0435 \u043e\u0431\u043e\u0440\u0443\u0434\u043e\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u0438 \u0441\u0438\u0441\u0442\u0435\u043c\u044b",
                            "rubric-id": 184107475
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "user_id": "0ba1f0e613c9b1db5fcbddd342e44a15"
    },
```

...and so on for several hundred of thousand lines.

If I remove spaces and commas between JSON objects manually, this code (which I've found on Stackoverflow) seems to work:

```
import json

json_objects = []

def stream_read_json(file):
    start_pos = 0
    while True:
        try:
            obj = json.load(file)
            yield obj
            return
        except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
            file.seek(start_pos)
            json_str = file.read(e.pos)
            obj = json.loads(json_str)
            start_pos += e.pos
            yield obj


with open('task1.json', 'r') as source:
    objCount = 0 
    for data in stream_read_json(source):
        json_objects.append(data)
        objCount += 1
        print('Added ' + str(objCount) + 'th json object.')
```

But I just can't find anywhere how to get rid of this spaces and commas while reading JSON file. It is even more frustrating that I can't find any tutorial or manual how to write JSON parser with Python for different cases to be able to do it by myself without bothering Stackoverflow.

Any hints and thoughts will be very appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it valid JSON minus the fact it appears to be missing a `[` at the start and a `]` at the end? 'cos - adding those in - that sample data loads fine using `json.load`

Comment: @JonClements oh, you are right, this way it works just fine. I can't believe that I've spent so much time only because of two missing square brackets. Thank you! :)